# How to make class dependent on another?

Tags: c++, class, dependencies

I've got to make 2 classes in c++, let's say:

class Foo, and class Bar

They key here is that class Bar can only be created when class Foo exist, how do i do that?
I mean there can't be a single Bar class unless Foo is created.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does Foo own a Bar? it would seem to me the most likely case...

Comment: Functions in Foo use functions from Bar. I am a beginner so I don't really know if Foo shoud own Bar

Comment: I think you'll probably have to clarify a bit more about what your use for Foo and Bar is. What is Foo's responsibility and what is Bar's responsibility, and how do they interact are questions you should be asking yourself.

Comment: I guess you mean that it should be possible to create an object of class Bar only when an object of class Foo exists? (class are only types and as such don't "exist", at most they can be known or unkown) This you can achive by defining a constructor that requires a reference of a Foo object.

Comment: Rene you are right.
Foo uses a function from bar that takes an input from a user. Should i make a bar constructor into Foo?

Comment: This sounds like a design flaw or a misuse of classes. Otherwise it would simply be impossible to compile one without the other.